# Is it possible to change the look and feel of remote X applications running under Xming?

Tags: fonts, themes, gtk, xming

I am running Eclipse remotely right now, in Xming on my Windows pc, through an ssh tunnel from my laptop running Ubuntu 11.10.

As seen below, it doesn't look that bad, but it seems that my applications defaults to the standard theme when it cannot find any others for GTK+ applications.

Is there anything I can do about this? Also it would be nice if I could do something about the font settings to make it more easily readable.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just install Eclipse for Windows?

Comment: If I wanted to run Eclipse natively from Windows, I would have done that. So that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Well, this question isn't on-topic of Ask Ubuntu. GTK+ Styling is done by Windows after you forward through Xming.

Comment: No, it is rendered by Xming, and I cannot see how that would be offtopic, since it is nothing but a windows port of X, same rules for the protocol still apply. You are really not doing me a favor here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install gtk-chtheme

```
$ sudo apt-get install gtk-chtheme
```

and call it in a terminal opened in Xming

```
$ gtk-chtheme
```

Also, you can use LXAppearance:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lxappearance
```

and call it as

```
$ lxappearance
```

(LXAppearance is, technically, part of LXDE, but the configuration file it creates is generic for GTK 2.0)

Comment: This works great on with remote-X applications from Mint displayed on Xquartz, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

X applications get their fonts from the X server — Xming in this case. You can [copy Windows fonts to your Xming font directory](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/fonts.php) to give Eclipse access to more fonts.

I'd love to see an answer to the other part of your question. Wish I had one.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you wont get that really pretty. This is not only a XMing problem, but also a general GTK/Eclipse Theming thing.

Just use the native Windows install and be happy.

It does help to check the Xserver configuration for the font path and server and it might also help to switch your window manager on X11 site (session manager or environment depending on what you use).

Eclipse 4.2 also has some theming problems, it might help to remove the CSS files like described here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/872214/